# ASP.NET Core 3: how to remove area from routing (from url) for one specific area?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

How to remove area from routing (from url) for one specific area ?

One option is to configure `AddRazorPages` this way (it works):

```
serviceCollection.AddRazorPages(
                options =>
                {
                    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("MyArea", "/MyPage1", "MyPage1");
                    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("MyArea", "/MyPage2", "MyPage2");
                    // ...                    
                });
```

But do we have the option to do it without looping through all pages?

Something like:

```
serviceCollection.AddRazorPages(
                options =>
                {
                    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("MyArea", "/*", "*");

                    // ...                    
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [PageRouteModelConvention](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/custom-route-conventions), a class that implements `IPageRouteModelConvention`, which had an `Apply` method where you an alter the route template (among other things):

```
public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
{
    if(model.RelativePath.StartsWith("/Areas/MyArea"))
    {
        foreach(var selector in model.Selectors)
        {
            selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template.Replace("MyArea", string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Register your convention in `ConfigureServices`:

```
options.Conventions.Add(new MyCustomPageRouteModelConvention());
```